# Remove crop from transformation tool

Tags: java, android, photoeditorsdk

I need to remove the crop feature from the TransformEditorTool or maybe leave only one aspect but I am not managing to do it.
I've tried add a aspectRatio as the documentation says(code below), but then every time I open the editor it redirects me for the transformation screen at first
What I've tried:

```
    config.setAspects(new CropAspectConfig(20, 25));
```

And I've also tried to set the aspect direct into configuration on the TransformEditorTool, not in the global config, but then I am getting a null reference error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

to prevent this behavior, set ForceCrop to "SHOW_NEVER".

```
    settingsList.getSettingsModel(TransformSettings.class).setForceCropMode(ForceCrop.SHOW_NEVER)
```

Best,
Sven